# Remove back slash from Json String in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, backslash

i need some help for Remove Back slash from Json String.

Here is the Response which i Get From Server side.

```
"response":"{\"time_zone\":\"\",\"session_token\":\"abcdefgHijklomopqrstuvwxyz\",\"user_login\":\"abc\",\"user_profile_img\":\"http://jhjhjhj.org/system/photos/62/medium/images.jpg?1462446436\",\"success\":\"0\",\"org_admin\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"62\",\"user_org_id\":\"101\",\"phone_mobile\":\"510-427-9639\",\"user_email\":\"abc@pdmoffice.com\"}"}
```

what i have don for Remove Backslash from this String

result.replaceAll("\\","");

than After it will give me This String which is not in Json Formate.

```
{"response":"{"time_zone":"","session_token":"nskfndkjfsfsdffjsdfd","user_login":"newoff2","user_profile_img":"http://absdds.org/system/photos/62/medium/images.jpg?1462446436","success":"0","org_admin":"","user_id":"62","user_org_id":"101","phone_mobile":"510-427-9639","user_email":"hjhjh@pdmoffice.com"}"}
```

it Give me Exaption

```
    org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 17 of 

{"response":"{"time_zone":"","session_token":"kjshhdscncnxzcxclx","user_login":"newoff2","user_profile_img":"http://abcd.org/system/photos/62/medium/images.jpg?1462446436","success":"0","org_admin":"","user_id":"62","user_org_id":"101","phone_mobile":"510-427-9898","user_email":"sdgas@pdmoffice.com"}"}
```

How Can i remove this Back slash with Proper Json Formate ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix the server from escaping the quotes... Don't fix the Java code

Comment: Exactly, do not edit the response code, find a converter or a correct json reader. Or for the best practice, fix the code for webservice side.

Comment: Maybe, jodatime may fix your problem.

Comment: @RushDroid Did you manage to solve this issue in Android Side? or did u fix it in Server side?

Comment: @hemanthkumar i resolve this issue from android side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command

```
result.replaceAll("\\","");
```

is correct and if you try to display the server response with an online json formatter (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) you can clearly see that the string is not correctly formatted. The double quotes after the "response" and one at the end are not required.

Comment: I don't think that will work. What if the JSON data actually had a backslash in a string, for example?

Comment: I agree with you @cricket_007, but I was focused on the specific example RushDroid provided

Comment: It will not work most cases where the json itself contains a backslash as its value such as a web url. The url value then will be destroyed completely. Wrong answer is accepted. I posted the proper answer in below post. Alas the questioner does not know that what dangerous code he pushed into his project.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED: August 2019**
Use google's Gson for parsing to Json by omitting backslash automatically:

**JAVA CODE:**

```
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse("your jsonString with backslash").getAsJsonObject();
```

**KOTLIN CODE:**

```
    val jsonParser = JsonParser()
    val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse("your jsonString with backslash").asJsonObject
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to remove backslashes from JSON string.

```
s = Your String with Back Slash
```

For converting String to JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
```

For converting String to JSONArray:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and it will work fine

```
String jsonStr4 = jsonStr3.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer to help future readers?