# retrofit generate unformatted complex json object

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am having a very strange problem

I am trying to build a complex json object which contains nested json

I have created it but when I send the request it crash

here is the format that I need

```
{"JR":"{"Text":"","userID":4,"Context":"","ClinicId":1}","TO":"getWatsonMessage","ver":2}
```

what I found in the request body as following:

```
{"JR":"{\"Text\":\"\",\"userID\":4,\"Context\":\"\",\"ClinicId\":1}","TO":"getWatsonMessage","ver":2}
```

which make the app crash

here is my code

```
data class MyBody @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @SerializedName("ver") val version: Int,
    @SerializedName("TO") val methodName: String,
    @SerializedName("JR") val jsonParams: String,
    @SerializedName("Method") var methodType: String? = null
)
```

and this is how I create the sub json object

```
val jsonJR = JSONObject()
        jsonJR.put("Text",text)
        jsonJR.put("userID",userId)
        jsonJR.put("Context",context)
        jsonJR.put("ClinicId",clinicId)
```

can anyone please help ?

Comment: have you tried [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687040/remove-back-slash-from-json-string-in-android)

Comment: yes first thing and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is with your JR of type String.
All the other params are in the proper format right?
So, I suggest that you provide type JR to another custom data class like

data class JRDataClass{
Text : String,
//and the rest of the data types
}

Comment: and use val jsonParams : JRDataClass